# Django_comments: What's the proper way to override post_comment()?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-comments

I'm trying to customize `django_comments` app ([github repo](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments), [docs](https://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

The default `get_form_target()` returns `django_comments.views.post_comment`, which is a function-based view. `post_comment()`, in turn, returns a `HttpRedirectResponse` to the value of `next` (if specified) or to a default confirmation page.

See default post_comment() implementation [here](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/master/django_comments/views/comments.py#L34).

I need to add a couple lines of logic to the `post_comment()`. Can I override it to where it still does the default implementation, but with the extra logic? I could just copy the original code and modify it, but it feels like a lot of code duplication for just adding a couple lines of custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where your logic happens relative to what is happening in the current `post_comment()`. If you simply want to do something *before* `post_comment()`, then just copy a pointer to the existing func, create your func, and call the original at the end. Finally, you can MonkeyPatch it in by assigning your function to the other module's `post_comment()`.

OTOH, if what you want to do is change what's happening *inside* the current func, then you may have to make a copy of the code, then MonkeyPatch as above.

Note well: even with good comments warning people about what this is doing, MonkeyPatching represents a maintenance timebomb just waiting to go off at some inconvenient time in the future.